# Ajax reloading an entire object after updating an attribute

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.new_question_vote').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $form = $(event.currentTarget);
    $count = $form.find('.count');
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: $form.attr('action'),
      dataType: "json",
      success: function() {
    $updatedCount = parseFloat($count.text()) + 1;
    $count.text($updatedCount);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

I have questions that are ordered on a page by up-votes.  I have the vote count uploading without reloading the entire page, but the events are not re-ordering based on vote counts.  I am unsure how to update the entire opject with the vote count so the events re-order.  $form is the question object and $count is the vote count for that object.  This is a rails app the question has many votes.  Any pointers would be helpful.  Thanks

Comment: You will need to swap the positions in the success callback.

Comment: You could assign the values to data attribute, and then on you callback sort it based on that. Look at this example http://jsfiddle.net/UdvDD/

Comment: im confused to what the .dataset.percentage is doing?

Comment: hey Alex i got the function to work but there is one bug I can not figure out...if the questions have the same votes they are flip-flopped when voting on a question that is not associated with either of the questions that have the same vote count....any idea how to solve this issue?